# Google Analytics and Salesforce

Tags: analytics, form, salesforce-classic, google

I want to bring the value of a custom dimension in Google Analytics to Salesforce. I know it should be possible using the web-to-load form, but I can't find a clear answer to how. Note: I'm not talking about the utm tags, but rather just any (custom) variable.